# where to load model from file in flutter apps?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, async-await, initialization

Suppose I store my data in a dedicated repo class like so:

```
class UrlEntry {
  final String url;

  final String title;

  UrlEntry({@required this.url, this.title});
}

class UrlRepository with ChangeNotifier {

  List<UrlEntry> urlEntries = new List<UrlEntry>();

  // Returns the urls as a separate list. Modifyable, but doesnt change state.
  List<UrlEntry> getUrls() => new List<UrlEntry>.from(urlEntries);

  add(UrlEntry url) {
      this.urlEntries.add(url);
      print(
          "url entry ${url.url} added. Now having ${urlEntries.length} entries ");
      notifyListeners();
  }

  removeByUrl(String url) {
      var beforeCount = this.urlEntries.length;
      this.urlEntries.removeWhere((entry) => entry.url == url);
      var afterCount = this.urlEntries.length;
      if (beforeCount != afterCount) notifyListeners();
      print("removed: ${beforeCount != afterCount}");
  }

  save() async {
      final storageFile = await composeStorageFile();
      print("storage file is '${storageFile.path}");
      if (await storageFile.exists()) {
        print("deleting existing file");
        await storageFile.delete();
      }
      if (urlEntries == null || urlEntries.length < 1) {
        print("no entries to save");
        return false;
      }
      print(
          "saving ${urlEntries.length} url entries to file $storageFile} ...");

      for (var entry in urlEntries) {
        await storageFile.writeAsString('${entry.url} ${entry.title}',
            mode: FileMode.append);
      }
  }

  Future<File> composeStorageFile() async {
    Directory storageDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return File('${storageDir.path}/url_collection.lst');
  }

  void dispose() async {
    super.dispose();
    print("disposing ...");
    urlEntries.clear();
    this.urlEntries = null;
  }

  load() async {
      final storageFile = await composeStorageFile();
      if (!await storageFile.exists()) {
        print("storage file  ${storageFile.path}  not existing - not loading");
        return false;
      }
      print("loading file ${storageFile.path}");
      urlEntries = List <UrlEntry> () ;
      final fileLines = storageFile.readAsLinesSync() ;

      for (var line in fileLines) {
        var separatorIndex = line.indexOf(' ') ;
        final url = line.substring(0, separatorIndex) ;
        var title = line.substring(separatorIndex+1) ;
        if (title == 'null') title = null ;
        urlEntries.add(new UrlEntry(url: url, title: title)) ;
      }
      notifyListeners() ;
  }
}
```

Above code has several issues I unfortunately donnot know how to circumvent:

1. most of the methods of UrlRepository are async. This is because  of *getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()* being async. I think former  is an absolute flaw but introducing semaphores here to create an artificial bottleneck would pollute the code, so I still stick to async; but call me old-fashioned -  I dont like the idea having save and load operations being theoretically able to overlap each other.  I mean, with getApplicationDocumentsDirectory, we're talking about a simple configurational detail that will not need much computational power to compute, nor to store, nor will it change that often and it pollutes the code with otherwise unnessecary stuff. So, Is there another way to get the results of *getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()* without await / async / then ?
2. If this is not the case - where should I put the call to save()? My first idea was to save data not every model change, but instead at the latest possible executional place, which is one of the dispose-related methods, like so:

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  UrlRepository urlRepository;

...


  @override
  void deactivate() async {
    await urlRepository.save() ;
    super.deactivate();
  }
```

Unfortunately this results in urlRepository.save() being executed only the half, no matter whether I call it in a unit test, on a avd or on a real device. Right in the middle its terminated - I checked that with printouts. I think this is because, being forced *again* to make a completely unrelated method async (here *deactivate()*), I have to accept  that execution is not granted to terminate at the return command, but earlier (?). I tried to put the call  to MyState.dispose() as well as to  urlRepository.dispose() with the same result *except* I cannot make the dispose methods async and hence just call save() async and hope everything has been saved before super.dispose() kicks in,...

3. I thought it natural to load the repositotry state inside of  initState(), but I want to make sure that either the load  has completed  *before* creating widgets (ie calling the builder), or will be loaded after all widgets have already been in place so the model change will trigger rebuild. Since load() has to be async for known reasons and initState is not, I cannot assure even one of above cases and stick with urlRepository.load() and hope the best. So, where to put the call to urlRepository.load() ?

Answer (score 0):

First: You have to use async/await methods because you don't know what the user's device may be doing while running your application, so even though the device might be performing a process that "doesn't need much power computational" that process may take a little longer than expected.

Second: Do not trust in `deactivate()` and `dispose()` functions, the user could kill your app and it would never do the save process. I'm not really sure how to automate this process. I suggest you do it manually somewhere in your code.

Third: Don't use initState() to load your data, you should use a FutureBuilder in which the future parameter is your `urlRepository.load()` function, while its loading you can show a `CircularProgressIndicator()` and if it has data you show your widget.

Example:

```dart
@override
Widget build() {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: urlRepository.load() // without await keyword
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(!snapshot.hasData)
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      return YourWidget(); // if snapshot.hasData is true the process has finished
    }
  );
}
```

Psdt: It might be useful if `urlRepository.load()` would return something like a bool. Doing this you could show a widget if `snapshot.data` is true or another widget if `snapshot.data` is false.

Comment: Foremost  - thank you for your quick answer -legend! Second: I donnot complain about async / await in general, but specifically about getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() being async *despite* being a trivial function. Third: okay that menas directly that I have to save the file every time the model changes, otherwise I'll lose data. I thought from somewhere in the docs that dispose() being "very important to implement" - hence called with confidence no matter wether app is killed or paused... third: thank you for the snippet! I'll try that out and come back later.

Comment: I tried the FutureBuilder, and it didnt work. The problem is that I use a ChangeNotifierProvider that is settled below the builder; so if urlRepo.load returns from loading, the future builder is not informed about the model cfhange and cannot  replace the spinner.. Hence the spinner spins forever.